# Stacking select / option tags above each other

Tags: html

I’m trying to create a simple page with a side bar that has a group of drop down boxes stacked above each other running down the left side of my page. A vague example follows:

```
HEADER---------------------------------->
[drop down box1]

[drop down box1]       BODY

[drop down box1]

[drop down box1]
```

I’ve already got the body and header as well as the parameters of the side bar/header/body set. I just need to figure out how to stack these drop down boxes.

```
<div class="side-bar">
  <select class="option-one">
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
  </select>

  <select class="option-two">
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
  </select>

  <select class="option-three">
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
  </select>

  <select class="option-four">
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried something with CSS? If so, [edit] the question to include the CSS as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you could approach this problem - you can take your pick:

**1: With an unordered list**

```
<div class="side-bar">
 <ul class="select-elements">
  <li>
  <select>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
  </select>
  </li>

  <li>
  <select>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
  </select>
  </li>

  <li>
  <select>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
  </select>
  </li>

  <li>
  <select>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
  </select>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

This will put each select group on a new line, abeit with bullet points next to them. To remove the bullets, then add this CSS:

```
select-elements li {
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

**2: With line breaks**

The unclosed `<br>` tag is replaced with a line break in HTML. Using `<br>` tags, your sidebar code looks like this:

```
<div class="side-bar">
      <select>
        <option>test</option>
        <option>test</option>
        <option>test</option>
      </select><br>

      <select>
        <option>test</option>
        <option>test</option>
        <option>test</option>
      </select><br>

      <select>
        <option>test</option>
        <option>test</option>
        <option>test</option>
      </select><br>

      <select>
        <option>test</option>
        <option>test</option>
        <option>test</option>
      </select><br>
</div>
```

**3: With display:block**

With CSS, you can tell an element that it displays on it's own line as a block-level element:

```
side-bar select {
    display:block;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `<select>` elements to stack you can use `display: block`. You simply add one line of CSS, and no extra markup in your HTML is needed.

**CSS**

```css
select {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="side-bar">
  <select class="option-one">
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
  </select>

  <select class="option-two">
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
  </select>

  <select class="option-three">
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
  </select>

  <select class="option-four">
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just placing each select statement in a div. Divs are generic block level elements so divs will automatically stack on top of each other. You can also place other things within the div such as a label etc. and the stacking will still work.

```
<div class="side-bar">
  <div><select class="option-one">
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
  </select></div>

  <div><select class="option-two">
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
  </select></div>

  <div><select class="option-three">
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
  </select></div>

  <div><select class="option-four">
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
  </select></div>
</div>
```